# No Man's Sky - All Black Holes Created Equal?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Without giving any spoilers away - lets say I have the choice between multiple black holes at the same relative distance from me... Is there any reason why I would choose one over another? i.e. some indication that one would bring me closer to the center of the galaxy or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in appearance of black holes or anything that would suggest where you will end up before entering one. Choosing which to enter and where you end up would be purely luck.

I imagine you could however, save your game before entering each black hole and making a note of each exit, then going back and choosing whichever location you liked more. Assuming of course each black hole has a pre-determined ending location that will be the same each time you enter.